# SpringDAO: How RowMapper works internally to fetch data from database

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

below are the code for fetching records from database and show it to console. But I'm wonder how the `jdbcTemplate.query(sql, RowMapper rm)` method working like how **ResultSet** instantiate in `mapRow()` function and what's the usage of the **2nd parameter** of this method. Can anyone explain how `jdbcTemplate.query(sql, RowMapper rm)` methods work?

Assume **config.xml**, **Employee bean class** and **EmployeeDAO interface** already provided and below is the code provided for **EmployeeDaoImpl class**

**Repository class**

```
@Repository(value="empDAO")
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO{
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setDs(DataSource ds) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Employee> selectAllEmployee() {
        String sql = "select * from Employee";
        List<Employee> listOfEmployee = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        listOfEmployee  = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper<Employee>(){
            public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException{
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.setEmployeeId(rs.getInt("employeeId"));
                employee.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                employee.setSalary(rs.getDouble("salary"));

                return employee;
            }
        });

        return listOfEmployee;
    }
}
```

Comment: A rowMapper uses the design pattern builder to build your Object from an Sql ResultSet , I don't understand what i your question exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, jdbcTemplate will create a prepared statement from your SQL, execute the statement, get back the resultset and use the RowMapper to map each row to a Java object.

Let's reference the document from Spring: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html